# Ignore missing method in JAX-WS client

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I have a model that is used to create a Web Service endpoint on a server. The same model is used for the client. However when a new operation is added to the server but the client still uses the older model, service creation fails with an exception like the following (line breaks added for clarity):

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException:
  Method someNewMethod is exposed as WebMethod, but there is no
  corresponding wsdl operation with name someNewMethod in the
  wsdl:portType{http://example.com}MyService
```

I understand the problem but is it possible to ignore this? I'd like to be backwards compatible when consuming the Web service. As long as methods are merely added this should work just fine most of the time.

The problem occurs in the `getPort` method:

```
Service s = Service.create(
    new URL("http://example.com/foo?wsdl"),
    new QName("http://example.com", "MyService"));
MyService m = s.getPort(MyService.class);
```

Comment: What web service library are you using? Many packages implement JAX-WS. CXF, for example, won't do this.

Comment: @bmargulies We use the jaxws RI from Oracle.

Comment: Are you using the address of the endpoint from the WSDL or are you setting it at runtime after you get an instance of the port?

Comment: @Nathan The WSDL contains the location of the port. I don't set any address manually besides the one of the WSDL itself.

Comment: You might try adding a copy of the WSDL locally and setting the wsdlLocation to that local copy.  What you're running into may be the constructor loading the wsdl from wsdlLocation before making the port.  You should probably put a bogus address for the endpoint in the local copy (like urn:none or something) to see if it is picking up the endpoint address from the live copy, but validating the operations from the local copy.  Otherwise, a local copy and manually setting the endpoint url would work if you don't really need to get the endpoint address from the wsdl.

Comment: @Nathan Doesn't really seem very convenient (e.g. the WSDL is splitted into multiple WSDLs and XSDs by JAX-WS on the server side) but I don't see any other solution either. It's worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference. 
You can also annotate the method with

```
@WebMethod(exclude=true)
```

This will make sure the method is ignored for comparing with the wsdl.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks... I use Weblogic 12.2.1.3 with Java 8 and Spring Boot 1.5.15

Answer (score 0):

Use an local WSDL File:
 
The client App has an local WSDL File of the service e.g inside the jar file.

The you get it with

```
URL wsdlURL = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResource("MyWebService.wsdl");
```

That worked for a App that i wrote. The server later extended an additional WSDL attribute, while the client still uses the local one.

Comment: I'll have to see if that works. The WSDL is generated by JAX-WS and split into multiple WSDL and schema files (cuz that's how JAX-WS rolls). I guess those have to be merged or the lookup of the `schemaLocation` fails.

Comment: The generated schema files source code, of course in the client stays. It is only neccessary that the schema stays compatible, and that the new fields, methods, are marked as optional (default, i think) in the server WSDL

Comment: Updated answer, in my case it was a change attribute, not a method

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the webservice reference and created again using the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your Service class contains a static constructor with a local wsdl file variable. Check if local wsdl file has the  *someNewMethod*. If not download the wsdl file from original Url and save to local. 
The soap address location value at the end of the wsdl is also important. 
Sometimes https turns to http.